# What's the difference between stateful logic and state in React?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

I'm going over the [hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) and they make it very clear

> The state of these components is completely independent. Hooks are a
>   way to reuse stateful logic, not state itself.

I want to be clear on the difference between these two things.

Answer (score 10):

That's saying that when you reuse a custom hook in multiple components, the actual state data will not be shared between those components. There will be a separate instance of the state data for each use of the hook.

If you do want to share the state, then you would be looking at using the `useContext` hook (which could also be used in a custom hook which would then mean the multiple uses of the hook could share state).

Answer (score 5):

*State is a combination of values that describe the current condition of the UI*. 
It can be shared between components in the sense that they are subscribed to its changes and, some of them, can perform changes on it.

*Stateful logic is any code that uses state*, but in the case of hooks I would define it as a behaviour created with the use of one or more hooks. It's like a perk that you're adding to a component. A perk is a good example because it tells you that its value is specific to that component, but more than one component can have that perk, that's why it's called reusable.

Answer (score 1):

It means a fresh instance of the state variable is instantiated at each and every place of that particular custom hook. And the states in the hook are not shared between the users of that custom hook. They are peculiar for each user of that hook. Every time you use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully isolated.

Answer (score 0):

*State* is state in class component, the only way to change state is setState.

*Stateful logic* is some behaviors including hook and custom hook with state, use behavior to change state.

Answer (score 0):

in my point of view:

UI are interactive base on events and change over **time**.

react use **state** to handle(rerender) UI over the times.(specific component version in specific time)

many **logics**(functions) must use current state value(s) to return results (stateful logics)

some stateful logics(functions) are usable for multiple components, to **sharing** them we could use Hooks.